# Magento collection complex condition or union approach

Tags: magento

Long story short, I need to get a collection that should be filtered using the following condition: where (A and (B or C) or (D and (E or F)). 
I can do them separately using:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customModule/customModel')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('fieldA', valA)
->addFieldToFilter(
  array('fieldB', 'fieldC'),
  array(
      array('eq' => valB),
      array('eq' => valC)
  )
);
```

But i don't know if I can make a single collection which would combine the two. I haven't found a "Magento" way of doing this. I also though of performing a union between them using

```
$collection1->getSelect()->union(array($collection2->getSelect()));
```

but it doesn't work. After the above statement, printing the $collection1->getSelect()->__toString() displays:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `customModel` AS `main_table` WHERE..
```

which throws an error. For some reasons it concatenates the two select clauses rather then the two queries.

Can anyone suggest a fix in either direction? If I can either use Magento's native functions to perform the complex condition or how to fix the union?

Answer (score 1):

I've also searched far & wide for this but unfortunately it is not implemented.

There are some problems with using `UNION` without `DISTINCT`, because the `entity_id` in a collection has to be unique otherwise you'll get an exception from some code layers bellow yours.

### The Magento / Zend way:

It is possible by getting the underlying `Zend_Select` object and adding a union join in the Zend way. Meaning that the resulting query object(s) will be a `Zend_Query` which you will have to execute and fetch results on (the Zend way).

The pitfall of this is that the result is not a Magento Collection and the objects inside are not `Magento` model objects but `Zend_Db_Table_Row`.

### The way I solved it:

I created multiple separate collections for which I called `getAllIds()` (this triggers a separate query which only fetches the ids) and then I merged the resulting arrays of ids and created one "master collection" `WHERE entity_id IN(/*...*/)`.